# Get all images in a directory except retina

Tags: php

I have a php script which grabs all of the images in a set directory. The script works without fault. My issue is that I want it to only get none retina images. All of the retina images are named in the format 'image1@2x.jpg' whereas all of the regular images are named in the format 'image1.jpg'. With this in mind I want my script to discount any image that contains '@2x' in it's name.

My script is:

```
<?php
    $directory = 'images/';
    $dh = opendir($directory);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
    {
        $files[] = $filename;
    };
    $images = preg_grep ('/(\.gif|\.GIF|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.JPG|\.JPEG|\.png|\.PNG)$/i', $files);

    foreach ($images as $image)
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$directory.$image.'" alt="">';
    }
?>
```

The problem is I don't have the vocabulary to know what to search for in Google so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Use `stripos`. [Doc here.](http://php.net/stripos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your script a little shorter by using:

```
$directory = 'images/';

$allImages = glob($directory.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
$nonRetinaImages = preg_grep('/@2x/i', $allImages, PREG_GREP_INVERT);

foreach ($nonRetinaImages as $image)
{
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="">';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use stripos put this conditional in your foreach loop

```
if(stripos($image,'@2x') === false){
    echo '<img src="'.$directory.$image.'" alt="">';
}
```